# Mechanics of Plague of Toads: Does it deal 130% dmg each frog or all three frogs combine?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

> Plague of Toads
>
> Primary Cost: 34 Mana
>
> Release a handful of toads that deal 130% weapon damage as Poison to
>   enemies they come in contact with.

So is it 130% dmg per frog or its all 3 frogs combine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From experience, *each* frog does 130% damage per hit.  The other Witch Doctor skills that release multiple projectiles work similarly.

Comment: @agent866 thanks.  time to pwn some newbz!